# Upload file still in use *sometimes* when trying to move

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

After an image is uploaded to my server, my code moves it into a specific folder given by the user details. Sometimes I think it tries to move the file too fast or the upload file is still in use so 9/10 the function won't perform the move.

Is there a way to add a 'wait' or a way to check if a file is in use and possibly perform a while loop until the file is allowed to be moved?

Current move function in my controller:

```
while (!File.Exists(uploadedPath))
{
}
File.Move(uploadedPath, savePath);
```

PS. I intend to add in a counter to ensure the while loop doesn't get stuck and has a timeout.

Comment: Do you get an exception? If so, what is it?
Also, how are you updating the file? The way you say it would just be possible if you update it in an async way.

Comment: Show up some code, how do you save the file. 
Probably you will not be disposing saved file properly.

Comment: For reference, the exception I was getting: `IOException was unhandled by user code - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` I think the error came about because the server was trying to move the file too quickly while it was still in use/being uploaded. The while loop outlined in the answer solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have control over the code receiving the file, I would update it to notify the moving code when the file is received completely. Alternatively I would move the file from there or even save the file where it should be eventually.

Otherwise, it will be a hack. You need

1. Try to move the file,
2. Catch the exception if it doesn't move
3. Use Thread.Sleep for a few sec
4. Go To 1

Something along the lines:

```
bool success = false;
for (var count = 0; !success && count < 10; ++count)
{
    try
    {
        File.Move(uploadedPath, savePath);
        success = true;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        Thread.Wait(1000);
    }
}
```

You also need to handle the situation when it cannot move the file at all. So it is a hack and should not be done in general if there are other ways to notify the moving code.

Also note:

From File.Move msdn:

> If you try to move a file **across disk volumes** and that file is in use,
>   the file is copied to the destination, but it is not deleted from the
>   source.

which means that your file will remain in the received files directory after moving.

Comment: This solved it for me thanks, when watching the two folders (upload and destination folder) you could see on every 10th or so upload, there would be a little delay on the file move but this time instead of being stuck it would retry the move and succeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are UploadFile and MoveFile 2 different components that are independent of each other. If so I don't think it's a good architecture. I would recommend a way so as to have the UploadFile pass the control to MoveFile once it's part is done. This way you can avoid multiple processes trying to access the same file.

Comment: This would be preferred but the platforms I am using make this difficult. The upload is done on an android device which is displaying the ASP.NET MVC through a WebView. The way to trigger the upload is done through javascript in the view, which executes the android JavascriptInterface function which unfortunately, when accessing the upload action in the controller, comes from a different thread and doesn't contain any of the users original information, meaning the move path wouldn't be able to use the details I want.

Comment: Ok. I understand the problem now. But how is the MoveFile actually invoked? Does it keep looking into the folder contents and try to move the image file as soon as it finds one?

Comment: The question was solved above but to clarify, I create a randomly generated string before triggering the upload. The uploaded images' filename is set to this string and the movefile action is triggered after the upload action. So the movefile action has a while loop waiting to see if the file exists and once it does (meaning it has been uploaded successfully) it moves it to the specified path. (In this case a path which contains the clients username so that the uploaded files are sorted)

Comment: Thank you @BASmith. In this case even I feel handling the exception is the way to go. Cheers!